Why is TArray<string> not freed automatically?
program Project4;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  psAPI,
  Winapi.Windows,
  System.SysUtils;

type
  TSimpleTestClass = class
    buffer: TArray<string>;
  end;
  
  TMatrixTestClass = class
    buffer: TArray<TArray<string>>;
  end;

function CurrentProcessMemory: Cardinal;
var
  MemCounters: TProcessMemoryCounters;
begin
  MemCounters.cb := SizeOf(MemCounters);
  GetProcessMemoryInfo(GetCurrentProcess, @MemCounters, sizeOf(MemCounters));
  OutputDebugString(PChar(MemCounters.WorkingSetSize.ToString()));
end;

function GenerateRandomString(const ALength: Integer; const ACharSequence: String = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890'): String;
var
  Ch, SequenceLength: Integer;

begin
  SequenceLength := Length(ACharSequence);
  SetLength(Result, ALength);
  Randomize;

  for Ch := Low(Result) to High(Result) do
    Result[Ch] := ACharSequence.Chars[Random(SequenceLength)];
end;

var
  simpleObj: TSimpleTestClass;
  matrixObj: TMatrixTestClass;
  i: Integer;

begin
  try
    CurrentProcessMemory();
    simpleObj := TSimpleTestClass.Create();
    SetLength(simpleObj.buffer, 10000);
    for i := 0 to 9999 do simpleObj.buffer[i] := GenerateRandomString(32);
    simpleObj.Free();
    CurrentProcessMemory();
  
    matrixObj := TMatrixTestClass.Create();
    SetLength(matrixObj.buffer, 10000);
    for i := 0 to 9999 do begin
      SetLength(matrixObj.buffer[i], 1);
      matrixObj.buffer[i][0] := GenerateRandomString(32);
    end;
    matrixObj.Free();
    CurrentProcessMemory();
    matrixObj := nil; // For breakpoint
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.

I've been testing for something with the above code, and it seems that TArray in classes is not getting freed.
This is strange because as far as I know, TArray and string are both reference-counted. So why aren't they getting freed here when the instance of my class is ?
Edit : It's quite strange that the second run uses way less memory than the first, there's some compiler optimization there I believe. I tried with random strings and that didn't change.

Yes, dynamic arrays and strings (and any combination of such types) are automatically managed and will be freed automatically. But the way you try to measure this is likely confusing you.

@AndreasRejbrand The problem is that I do get this memory leak in an actual program, and it doesn't go away. Every time I run that part of the code, the RAM usage grows and never goes down. I'm not sure how I'm supposed to isolate the problem ?

You have to debug. This is not something that we can do for you, since we don't have access to your code.

All the memory that you are using in your code is being served by the RTL memory manager, which caches the memory it once acquired from the OS. That is why the number reported from the OS does not drop. The source you are using to get the consumed memory looks like some answers to this question but ignores the code from the accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437683/how-to-get-the-memory-used-by-a-delphi-program

This is on purpose as I do not use FastMM4.

If you are not using FastMM4 which memory manager are you using then. The source code you have provided does not contain any reference to unit of a specific memory manager. So the default Delphi memory manager would be used and that is FastMM4.

You are proceeding on a false assumption - that when you free memory in Delphi it is immediately released back to the OS. It is not.
The memory manager in Delphi allocates blocks in various sizes, and the small allocations are being handled internally by allocating bigger chunks from the OS (I believe there are three different block sizes used by the memory manager, but don't take my word as gospel on that issue) and then sub-allocating from this larger block (now under the control of the memory manager in your application).
When you release memory in Delphi, it is marked internally as free memory to be used in a later allocation, but it is still owned by your program (as seen from the OS).
So your functions that queries how much memory your process has acquired from the OS is not adjusted, unless the internal memory block it belongs to has been completely emptied, and - I think - is of the large size of the three block sizes I mentioned.
This is for optimization - constantly allocating and deallocating OS memory will have a significant impact on speed, so the memory manager tries to balance the times it has to allocate/free OS memory with the memory consumption of your application.
